# How to combine two mysql query with Union and Group them approprieatly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have two sql request from the same table and I would like to make both of them one in such a way that the result of the first one will sort of be concatenated with the result of the second.

This is my **first** request

```
$recup_id = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT MAX(`id`) AS id FROM mytable WHERE 
CASE 
WHEN `to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' THEN `read_statu`!='$id_ojm_peoples' 
END 

AND (`from_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' OR `to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples')  

AND (is_deleted!='$id_ojm_peoples' AND is_deleted >=0)   

GROUP BY (IF(`to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples', `from_id`, `to_id`))

ORDER BY `read_statu` ASC   LIMIT $nombre_de_messages_maximum

 ") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

And the second looks like the first but with a little difference.

```
$recup_id = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT MAX(`id`) AS id FROM mytable WHERE 

CASE 
WHEN `from_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' THEN `read_statu`>='0' 
END 

AND (`from_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' OR `to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples')  

AND (is_deleted!='$id_ojm_peoples' AND is_deleted >=0)   

GROUP BY (IF(`to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples', `from_id`, `to_id`)) 
ORDER BY `read_statu` ASC   LIMIT $nombre_de_messages_maximum

 ") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

I want the **second** request to be executed after the first so that it will return the result of the first request fist followed by the result of the second one and all in one request . The difference between the two request lies in

```
CASE 
WHEN `from_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' THEN `read_statu`>='0' 
END
```

And

```
CASE 
WHEN `to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' THEN `read_statu`!='$id_ojm_peoples' 
END
```

**Question**

I did

```
SELECT MAX(`id`) AS id FROM `mytable` WHERE

CASE 
WHEN `to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' THEN `read_statu`!='$id_ojm_peoples' 
END 

AND (`from_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' OR `to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples')  

AND (is_deleted!='$id_ojm_peoples' AND is_deleted >=0)   

GROUP BY (IF(`to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples', `from_id`, `to_id`))




UNION




SELECT MAX(`id`) AS id FROM `mytable` WHERE 

CASE 



WHEN `from_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' THEN `read_statu`>='0' 

END 




AND 


(`from_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' OR `to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples')  

AND  

(is_deleted!='$id_ojm_peoples' AND is_deleted >=0)   

GROUP BY (IF(`to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples', `from_id`, `to_id`))
```

However this did not group the users with their Id  but it rather gave me the users from the first query and then the users from the second query without grouping the users together. This is the output of the query above.

[image: Contact List]

As you can see some users appear twice instead of grouped.

Please how to combine this two query in such a way that it will **Distinctively return the result of the first query first** and then the result of the second query Grouped by the `from_id`, `to_id` ?

Comment: Can you edit the question with sample output of the both the queries and desired result

Comment: DISTINCT MAX is a meaningless concept

Comment: @NoDisplayName I have added the output.

Comment: @Strawberry  Yes i have edited it but do you have the solution for me ?

Answer (score -1):

UNION http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

That is how you combine 2 queries into 1 result.

I am not going to write it for you, try it yourself and ask for help when you need it.